# How to import a python file in python script more than once

Tags: python

Is it possible to import a python file more than once in a python script because i run a loop back to my driver file in a function by using the import command but it only works once? thanks

**edit:** Resolved myself thanks

Comment: Can you provide a short example of what you're trying to do, and what you expect to happen?

Comment: I figured it out now thanks for your time lol

Comment: @Clinton: please update the question with the answer you found, or write an answer to do so, for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 7):

You most probably should not use import for what you are trying to do.

Without further information I can only guess, but you should move the code in the module you import from the top level into a function, do the import once and than simply call the function from you loop.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest answer is to put the code you are trying to run inside a function like this

(inside your module that you are importing now):

```
def main():
    # All the code that currently does work goes in here 
    # rather than just in the module
```

(The module that does the importing)

```
import your_module #used to do the work

your_module.main() # now does the work (and you can call it multiple times)
# some other code
your_module.main() # do the work again
```

Answer (score 1):

The import statement -- by definition -- only imports once.

You can, if you want, try to use `execfile()` (or `eval()`) to execute a separate file more than once.

Answer (score 1):

While Tom Ley's answer is the correct approach, it *is* possible to import a module more than once, using the reload built-in.

```
module.py:
print "imported!"

>>> import module
imported!
>>> reload(module)
imported!
<module 'module' from 'module.pyc'>
```

Note that reload returns the module, allowing you to rebind it if necessary.

Comment: Would probably replace reload(module) with module = reload(module), just for clarity.

Comment: Also, see http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/notes/reloading.html.  It's not as simple as it appears.

Comment: Ali: I considered that, but the rebinding isn't essential for the reload, as the original binding is affected. I hoped pointing out that it returned the module would be enough.