# Using response.out.write from within an included file in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I think this is quite an easy question to answer, I just haven't been able to find anywhere detailing how to do it.

I'm developing a GAE app.

In my main file I have a few request handlers, for example:

```
class Query(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        queryDOI = cgi.escape(self.request.get('doiortitle'))
        import queryCosine
        self.response.out.write(queryCosine.cosine(queryDOI))
```

In that handler there I'm importing from a queryCosine.py script which is doing all of the work. If something in the queryCosine script fails, I'd like to be able to print a message or do a redirect.

Inside queryCosine.py there is just a normal Python function, so obviously doing things like

```
self.response.out.write("Done")
```

doesn't work. What should I use instead of self or what do I need to include within my included file? I've tried using Query.self.response.out.write instead but that doesn't work.

Comment: beaware that `import queryCosine` is not going to run the contents of queryCosine.py every time it is encountered, as I believe you may be expecting? .... it will only **run** the contents of the file the **first** time it is seen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I'll use the methods suggested in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276679/how-to-import-a-python-file-in-python-script-more-than-once) to fix this.

Comment: this is just not how `import` works in python. It sounds like you are quite new to Python so Welcome!, and maybe read over the [modules page](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it to the function.

#### main file:

```
import second

 ...
  second.somefunction(self.response.out.write)
```

#### second.py:

```
def somefunction(output):
  output('Done')
```

Comment: Hi, I need to pass a value to the function from the main file, so I'm not sure the `second.somefunction(self.response.out.write)` line is appropriate. I've used `self.response.out.write(queryCosine.cosine(queryDOI))` at the moment, and I can pass values to that by using `return 'Error'` then a `sys.exit()` to terminate the function early if I need to. However I'm now trying to find out how to use a redirect like `self.redirect("/error")` with this method.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. I throw an exception and then catch it with a try/except clause.

Answer (score 2):

A much better, more modular approach, is to have your `queryCosine.cosine` function throw an exception if something goes wrong. Then, your handler method can output the appropriate response depending on the return value or exception. This avoids unduly coupling the code that calculates whatever it is you're calculating to the webapp that hosts it.